# How to draw a view with animation in android?

Tags: android, view, android-animation

I want to draw view like this image [image: similar] with animation. First i want draw circle then eyes and then mouth(arch like view ) with smooth animation. can we achieve such kind of animation? . Here i am getting problem of positioning the view eye and arc mouth.

Comment: its easy to draw circle with following code                          Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
    c.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint)

Answer (score 1):

Try this please

**> AnimView.java**

```
   import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.RectF;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;

    public class AnimView  extends  SurfaceView implements Runnable,
    Callback  {

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Thread thread = null;
        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        boolean running=false;
        long time=0;

        int pos=0;

        public AnimView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        }


        public AnimView(Activity context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super(context);
            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        }


        public void onResumeMySurfaceView() {

            thread = new Thread(AnimView.this);
            thread.start();
            running=true;


        }

        public void onPauseMySurfaceView() {
            boolean retry = true;
            running = false;
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    thread.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //  e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    //  @Override
    //    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //            canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 20, paint);
    //            canvas.drawLine(20, 0, 0, 20, paint);
    //            Log.i("onDraw","Draw");
    //         
    //    }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            while(running)
            {
                if(time==0)
                {
                    time=System.currentTimeMillis();
                    pos=0;
                }
                if((System.currentTimeMillis()-time) >3000)
                {
                    pos=1;
                }

                if((System.currentTimeMillis()-time) >6000)
                {
                    pos=2;
                }

                if((System.currentTimeMillis()-time) >9000)
                {
                    pos=3;
                }

                if((System.currentTimeMillis()-time) >12000)
                {
                    pos=0;
                    time=System.currentTimeMillis();

                }




                Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                if(canvas!=null)
                {
                    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                canvas.drawRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(), paint);

                if(pos>0)
                {
                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

                canvas.drawCircle(200, 200, 50, paint);

                paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

                canvas.drawCircle(200, 200, 48, paint);
                }


                if(pos>1)
                {
                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

                canvas.drawCircle(175, 185, 5, paint);

                canvas.drawCircle(225, 185, 5, paint);
                }



                if(pos>2)
                {
                paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
                // opacity
                //p.setAlpha(0x80); //

                RectF rectF = new RectF(160, 160, 240, 240);


                canvas.drawArc (rectF, 45, 135, true, paint);


                 rectF = new RectF(159, 159, 238, 238);

                 paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

                canvas.drawArc (rectF, 35, 145, true, paint);
                }




                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }

                 Log.i("onDraw","Draw");
            }

        }

    }
```

**>MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    AnimView av;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        av=new AnimView(this);
        setContentView(av);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        av.onPauseMySurfaceView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        av.onResumeMySurfaceView();
    }

}
```

Comment: But animation is not smooth. i would like to draw view like same way but with animationsome thing like drawing with pencil. Do you have any suggestion for it. Thanks for quick reply as this help me in some way

Comment: You can make it smoother as you like by implementing a bit of programming logic, just create the path you want and draw it according to time.

Comment: @ArashAtaAfarin Solution is simply drawing circle and placing image on center of circle. thats it.